# To to unsubscribe from events before scene will be changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, action

I have 2 scenes and I need to unsubscribe from events before first scene will be changed.

```
public event Action ObjIndexChanged = () => { };

void HandleCommand(Command command)
    {
        switch (command.name)
        {
            case "LAUNCH":
                GameSettings.ObjIndex = Convert.ToInt32(command.data["structureId"]) - 1;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Main", LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            case "CHANGE":
                GameSettings.ObjIndex = Convert.ToInt32(command.data["structureId"]) - 1;
                ObjIndexChanged.Invoke();
                break;
            case "EXIT":
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Background", LoadSceneMode.Single);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And my GameManager:

```
private void Start()
{
    commandsReceiver.ObjIndexChanged += OnIndexChanged;
}

private void OnIndexChanged()
{
    //GameLogic
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    commandsReceiver.ObjIndexChanged -= OnIndexChanged;
}
```

1. I load MainScene. Action was invoked 1 time
2. Load Background scene
3. Load MainScene. Action was invoked 2 times
4. Load Background scene
5. Load MainScene. Action was invoked 3 times

Where is my mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

instead of subscribe events in the Start Function, subscribe in 
`void OnEnable()` 
Then Instead of Unsubscribe events in the Start Function, subscribe in 
`void OnDisable()`

Like this :

```
void OnEnable()
{
   commandsReceiver.ObjIndexChanged += OnIndexChanged;
}

void OnDisable()
{
   commandsReceiver.ObjIndexChanged -= OnIndexChanged;
}
```